# Pre flush head tag  with gzip support

Tags: http, apache2, gzip

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

There it is given it is good to preflush the head tag .

But I have a question will it help while using gzip ? (I am using apache2). 
I think full document will get gziped at one shot and then send to the client.

or is it also possible to have gzip as well as pre-flush the head tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

The original version of this question suggested we were dealing with HTTP headers rather than the `<head>` section on an HTML document. I will leave my original answer below, but it actually has no relevance to this specific question.

To answer the question about pre-flushing the `<head>` section of a document - while it would be possible to do this in combination with gzip, it is probably not possible without more granular control over the gzip process than Apache affords. It is possible to break a gzipped stream into chunks that can be decompressed on their own ([see this](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib_faq.html#faq28)) but if there is a way to control Apache's gzip implementation to such a degree then I am not aware of it.

Doing so would likely decrease the efficacy of the gzip, making the compressed size larger, and would only be worth doing when the `<head>` of a document was particularly large, say, greater than 10KB (this is a somewhat arbitrary value I arrived at by reading about how gzip works under the bonnet, and should definitely *not* be taken as gospel).

---

Original answer, relating to the HTTP headers:

Purely from the viewpoint of the HTTP protocol, rather than exactly how you would implement it on an Apache based server, I can't see any reason why you can't preflush the headers and also use gzip to compress the body. Keeping in mind that fact that the headers are *never* gzipped (if they were, how would the client know they had been?), the transfer encoding of the content should have no effect on when you send the headers.

There are, however a couple of things to keep in mind:

- Once the headers have been sent, you can't change your mind about the transfer encoding. So if you send the headers which state that the body will be gzipped, then realise that your body is only 4 bytes, your would still have to gzip it anyway, which would actually increase the size of the body. This probably wouldn't be a problem unless you were omitting the `Content-Length:` header which while possible, is bad practice as it means you cannot use persistent connections. This leads on to the next point...
- You cannot send a `Content-Length:` header in this secenario. This is because you don't know what the size of the body is until you have compressed it, by which time it is ready to send, so you are not really (from the server's point of view) preflushing the headers, even if you do send them seperately before you start to send the body.
- If it takes you a long time time to compress the body of the message (slow/heavily loaded server, very large body etc etc), and you don't start the compression until after you have sent the headers, there is a risk the client may time out waiting for the rest of the response. This depends entirely on the client, but the are so many HTTP client implementations out there that this possibility cannot be totally discounted.

In short, yes it is possible to do it, but there is no catch-all, "Yes, do it" or "No, don't do it" answer - whether you would do it depends on each request and the nature of it's response.

Comment: sorry not to be clear. I misused header what I meant was head tag

Comment: Ahh right. Well in that case, it could be done but is probably impossible without more granular control over the gzip process than Apache will give you. Doing this would also reduce the efficacy of the gzip, meaning you would lose some of the compression. I would say it would only be worth doing this when you had a very large `<head>` section, if you could do it at all from Apache.

Comment: @Vivek I have edited my answer to reflect the information you want.