# Gzip or ob_flush()? which is better?

Tags: php, compression, gzip

I just finished reading [this post](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#flush)

> - The loading time of webpages is improved by enabling gzip compression on server.
> - Better user experience can be gained by flushing the content in webpages.

But the problem is flush() can't work when gzip(apache) compression is enabled.

1. Any solution for this? (ie, can  flush() and gzip can work at same time?)
2. If not, flush() or gzip? Which is better?
3. Or there is any alternate strategies for reducing load time.

Comment: "flush() or gzip is better" --- it looks like: which is better - banana or jumping.

Comment: it may look like  'banana or jumping' but both have effect on page load time.and as per my information both can't used together..so it do matter . right ?

Comment: Gzip is used to compress response, in order to transfer less content.
flush will output current output buffer. They are totally different things.

Comment: i asked this question since i can't get enough info from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359790/pre-flush-head-tag-with-gzip-support

Comment: Flush and gzip are both used for the same thing - i.e. decreasing page load times. If you have a lot of heavy php in the `<body>` of your page then `flush()` after your `<head>` HTML code. This way the browser can start loading CSS and Javascript files before your PHP has completed. If you've separated the PHP from the HTML (as you should - see MVC patterns) then this won't help all that much, so I would use gzip to decrease page load times by sending less data to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

1. They can not be used together.
2. If your total server rendering time of the page is high (say more than 250ms or so), go for flush (until you fixed the scripts). Else stick with the proper gzip.
3. You have a whole list of them already on the link you posted.

Comment: But I just told you the reasoning you can use to chose. It does not tell you that you need to employ all the techniques described together, does it?

Answer (score 0):

They absolutely can be used together.  There were early versions of mod_deflate where it would not stream the compression and support chunked encoding but that is no longer the case (just watch out for the size of the deflate buffers) - http://www.phpied.com/progressive-rendering-via-multiple-flushes/